# Resizing element by dragging in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

Scaling HTML element using vanilla javascript. I wanted to scale elements in HTML body using vanilla javascript but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function scaleBlock() {
    const container = document.getElementById('container');
    var mouseDownNow = false;

    function scaleBlockOnMouseMove(element) {
        elementDraggableHeight = element.target.getBoundingClientRect().bottom; // element height
        elementDraggableWidth = element.target.getBoundingClientRect().right; // element width
        mouseVerticalPosition = element.clientY; // mouse vertical position (Y-axis)
        mouseHorizontalPosition = element.clientX; // mouse horizintal position (X-axis)
        if (element.target.className == 'container' && (elementDraggableHeight - 15 < mouseVerticalPosition && 
            mouseVerticalPosition <= elementDraggableHeight)) {
            element.target.style.cursor = 'ns-resize';
            container.style.height = (mouseVerticalPosition - (element.target.offsetTop - 10)) + 'px';
        } else if (element.target.className == 'container' && (elementDraggableWidth - 15 < mouseHorizontalPosition && 
            mouseHorizontalPosition <= elementDraggableWidth)) {
            element.target.style.cursor = 'ew-resize';
            container.style.width = (mouseHorizontalPosition - (element.target.offsetLeft - 10)) + 'px';
        } else {
            element.target.style.cursor = 'default';
        }
    }

    (function onListeners() { // IIFE
        container.onmousedown = (event) => {
            mouseDownNow = true;
            container.addEventListener('mousemove', scaleBlockOnMouseMove);
        }
        container.onmousemove = (element) => {
            if (element.target.className == 'container' && (element.target.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - 15 < element.clientY && 
                element.clientY <= element.target.getBoundingClientRect().bottom)) {
                element.target.style.cursor = 'ns-resize';
            } else if (element.target.className == 'container' && (element.target.getBoundingClientRect().right - 15 < element.clientX && 
                element.clientX <= element.target.getBoundingClientRect().right)) {
                element.target.style.cursor = 'ew-resize';
            } else {
                element.target.style.cursor = 'default';
            }
        }
        window.onmouseup = (event) => {
            if(mouseDownNow) {
                container.removeEventListener('mousemove', scaleBlockOnMouseMove);
                event.target.style.cursor = 'default';
            }
        }   
    })();
}

scaleBlock();
```

```css
html, body {
    font-family: arial
}
.wrapper {
    padding: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 50px auto;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: 50px auto;
    
    border-radius: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" id="container">  </div>
    </body>
</html>
```